# Ttrying to copy the content of files from source to destination, if file is .txt and if files have the same names and then ZIP each just copied file

Tags: python, copy, zip

I'm new to python and trying to copy the content of files from dir_A to dir_B. If file is .txt and if these files from dir_A and dir_B have the same names and after **zip** each of these newly copied files.

```
import os, shutil, zipfile

src_folder = "C:/Users/pushka/pythonApp1/src_folder"
dst_folder = "C:/Users/pushka/pythonApp1/dst_folder"

# only .txt files will be copied
ext = (".txt")

try:
    for src_f in os.scandir(src_folder):
        for dst_f in os.scandir(dst_folder):
            if src_f.path.endswith(ext) and os.path.basename(src_f) == os.path.basename(dst_f):
                # copy file
                shutil.copyfile(src_f, dst_f)

finally:
  print("The 'try except' is finished")
```

I have searched and tried several options to ZIP, but none of them work properly, so I need your help please

Comment: Keep a list of the copied files and add them to a new instance of [`zipfile.ZipFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile-objects).

Comment: Please give me an example of how to keep a list of copied files, that's exactly what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot, but here is the answer to my own question with your help

```
import os, shutil, zipfile

src_folder = "C:/Users/pushka/pythonApp1/src_folder"
dst_folder = "C:/Users/pushka/pythonApp1/dst_folder"

# only .txt files will be copied
ext = ".txt"
copied_files = []

for src_f in os.scandir(src_folder):
    for dst_f in os.scandir(dst_folder):
        if src_f.name.endswith(ext) and os.path.basename(src_f) == os.path.basename(dst_f):
            # copy file
                shutil.copyfile(src_f, dst_f)
                copied_files.append(dst_f)
print(copied_files)

for txt_file in copied_files:
    file_root = os.path.splitext(txt_file)[0]
    zip_file_name = file_root + '.zip'
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_name, mode='w') as zf:
        zf.write(txt_file, os.path.basename(txt_file))
```

Works as expected

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code a bit, but this should do the trick:

```
import os, shutil, zipfile

src_folder = "C:/Users/pushka/pythonApp1/src_folder"
dst_folder = "C:/Users/pushka/pythonApp1/dst_folder"

# only .txt files will be copied
ext = ".txt"
copied_files = []

for src_f in os.scandir(src_folder):
    if src_f.name.endswith(ext) and not src_f.is_dir():
        dst_f = os.path.join(dst_folder, src_f.name)
        if not os.path.exists(dst_f):
            shutil.copyfile(src_f, dst_f)
            copied_files.append(dst_f)

print(copied_files)

zipfile_name = os.path.join(dst_folder, "copied_files.zip")

if not os.path.exists(zipfile_name):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zipfile_name, "w") as zf:
        for txtfile in copied_files:
            print("Writing " + txtfile)
            zf.write(txtfile, os.path.split(txtfile)[-1])
```

It should be pretty self-explanatory, but I'll walk you through it. In the first `for` loop, we scan all entries in `src_folder`. If the name ends in `.txt` and it is not a directory, we create a path to the destination file. Then, as long as the destination file does not exist, we copy the source to the destination, and add the destination to the `copied_files` list.

After all the copying is done, we create the zip file's name. If it doesn't exist, we create it using the [`zipfile.ZipFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile-objects) context manager and write in each copied file (from the destination, not the source), stripping the full path from it in the archive.

Please note that, by default, the zipfile uses [`ZIP_STORED`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZIP_STORED) as the compression format - i.e., the data is not compressed. See the docs for the other supported compression formats if you need a compressed archive.

Answer (score -1):

- Simple format:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from typing import List
from zipfile import ZipFile

src_folder = Path("C:/Users/pushka/pythonApp1/src_folder")
dst_folder = Path("C:/Users/pushka/pythonApp1/dst_folder")
SUFFIX = ".txt"


def copy_file(from_path: Path, to_path: Path, copied) -> None:
    content = from_path.read_bytes()
    to_path.write_bytes(content)
    copied.append(to_path)
    print(f"Copy file: {from_path} --> {to_path}")


def zip_them(paths: List[Path]) -> str:
    filename = "copied.zip"
    with ZipFile(filename, "w") as z:
        for path in paths:
            z.write(path, path.name)
    return filename


def main():
    assert src_folder.exists(), f"path `{src_folder}` not found!"
    assert dst_folder.exists(), f"path `{dst_folder}` not found!"
    copied = []
    for p in src_folder.glob(f"*{SUFFIX}"):
        dst = dst_folder / p.name
        copy_file(p, dst, copied)
    fn = zip_them(copied)
    print(f"There are {len(copied)} files copied. And zipped to: {fn}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

- My prefer:

```py
from typing import List
from zipfile import ZipFile

import anyio  # pip install anyio
from anyio import Path


src_folder = Path("C:/Users/pushka/pythonApp1/src_folder")
dst_folder = Path("C:/Users/pushka/pythonApp1/dst_folder")


async def copy_file(from_path: Path, to_path: Path, copied) -> None:
    content = await from_path.read_bytes()
    await to_path.write_bytes(content)
    copied.append(to_path)
    print(f"copy file: {from_path} --> {to_path}")


def zip_them(paths: List[Path]) -> str:
    filename = "copied.zip"
    with ZipFile(filename, "w") as z:
        for path in paths:
            z.write(path, path.name)
    return filename


async def main():
    copied = []
    async with anyio.create_task_group() as tg:
        async for p in src_folder.glob("*.txt"):
            dst = dst_folder / p.name
            tg.start_soon(copy_file, p, dst, copied)
    fn = zip_them(copied)
    print(f"zip file created: {fn}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import timeit
    cost = timeit.timeit("anyio.run(main)", number=1, globals=globals())
    print("Cost:", round(cost, 2), "seconds.")
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, it works, yea, but not as expected.

Comment: sorry so many lines I don't understand yet, it zips the entire directory and doesn't copy anything

Comment: This is entirely too complex for the task at hand. It doesn't need to be done asynchronously, there's no need for a 3rd-party module, and as the OP indicated, it doesn't actually do half of what they're trying to do, which is copy the files. And, if you want to time the whole operation (which the OP never indicated was a priority), you should be using the built-in `timeit` module. That's what it's there for.

Comment: @MattDMo the timeit module is very good, thanks~

Comment: @art You can read article about concurrency and async / await, for example: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/zh/async/